# Override arguments of public function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify the variables of a public function. I am using a Listify WordPress theme and am trying to override the variable within child theme. Here is the function:

```
public function user_contactmethods( $methods, $user ) {
    $methods[ 'twitter' ] = __( 'Twitter URL', 'listify' );
    $methods[ 'facebook' ] = __( 'Facebook URL', 'listify' );
    $methods[ 'googleplus' ] = __( 'Google+ URL', 'listify' );
    $methods[ 'pinterest' ] = __( 'Pinterest URL', 'listify' );
    $methods[ 'linkedin' ] = __( 'LinkedIn URL', 'listify' );
    $methods[ 'github' ] = __( 'GitHub URL', 'listify' );

    return $methods;
}
```

I would like to change "GitHub URL" to something else, let's say google.url. Is it possible without modifying the core files?

Comment: Yes if they have provided filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use filter - more or less like below

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods', 11, 2 );

public function my_user_contactmethods( $methods, $user ) {
    /**
     * Modify $methods as you wish
     *
     */
    return $methods;
}
```

You should put this code in your WordPress theme `functions.php` file or in separate plugin.