# override Wordpress core public function

Tags: wordpress, function, overriding

I have 2 separate wp installs that are sharing the same database. My goal is to use the same post table and post meta table for both websites.

I have achieved that by adding in my config.php of the second site, the code:

```
define( 'CUSTOM_POST_TABLE', 'site1_posts' );
define( 'CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE', 'site1_postmeta' );
```

Also I have added in wp-includes/wp-db.php , public function tables, line 1026-1076 the code

```
if ( isset( $tables['posts'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['posts'] = CUSTOM_POST_TABLE;
        if ( isset( $tables['postmeta'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['postmeta'] = CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE;
```

Now both websites share the same posts but the issue is that the next time wordpress will be updated, I will loose the changes from wp-includes/wp-db.php

So I tried to override the public function with another function inside the function.php file of second website [Override arguments of public function in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984884/override-arguments-of-public-function-in-wordpress) but the website crashed and returns 500 error. Propably I am doing sth wrong.

The code I tried is

```
add_filter( 'tables', 'my_tables', 11, 2 );
public function my_tables( $scope = 'all', $prefix = true, $blog_id = 0 ) {

        if ( isset( $tables['posts'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['posts'] = CUSTOM_POST_TABLE;

        if ( isset( $tables['postmeta'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['postmeta'] = CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE;


    }

    return $tables;
}
```

The original code inside wp-includes/wp-db.php is

```
public function tables( $scope = 'all', $prefix = true, $blog_id = 0 ) {
    switch ( $scope ) {
        case 'all' :
            $tables = array_merge( $this->global_tables, $this->tables );
            if ( is_multisite() )
                $tables = array_merge( $tables, $this->ms_global_tables );
            break;
        case 'blog' :
            $tables = $this->tables;
            break;
        case 'global' :
            $tables = $this->global_tables;
            if ( is_multisite() )
                $tables = array_merge( $tables, $this->ms_global_tables );
            break;
        case 'ms_global' :
            $tables = $this->ms_global_tables;
            break;
        case 'old' :
            $tables = $this->old_tables;
            break;
        default :
            return array();
    }

    if ( $prefix ) {
        if ( ! $blog_id )
            $blog_id = $this->blogid;
        $blog_prefix = $this->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id );
        $base_prefix = $this->base_prefix;
        $global_tables = array_merge( $this->global_tables, $this->ms_global_tables );
        foreach ( $tables as $k => $table ) {
            if ( in_array( $table, $global_tables ) )
                $tables[ $table ] = $base_prefix . $table;
            else
                $tables[ $table ] = $blog_prefix . $table;
            unset( $tables[ $k ] );
        }

        if ( isset( $tables['users'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['users'] = CUSTOM_USER_TABLE;

        if ( isset( $tables['usermeta'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE' ) )
            $tables['usermeta'] = CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE;
    }

    return $tables;
}
```

How could override it so I won't loose my changes after the next update?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  1. Never edit WP core, never. If you have to edit it, it means your approach is wrong and you need different approach which doesn't require core editing.   2. WordPress have very large actions and filters which helps to change almost anything - during rendering.  3. If actions and fitlers can't solve your problem, build second website on WP REST API. It will solve your problem, it would be stable and correct solution.

Comment: Yeah, listen to Elvin85, that's a disaster waiting to happen. If you want to have identical content, you'll probably also want (or have no reason not to) identical plugins. If you want different themes, install both and change it with a filter on `template`. Change options with filters as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advices janh and Elvin85! Is there a way that I could override this function with a snippet inside my functions.php? What I tried is  ` add_filter( 'tables', 'my_tables', 11, 2 );
public function my_tables( $scope = 'all', $prefix = true, $blog_id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $tables['posts'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_TABLE' ) ) $tables['posts'] = CUSTOM_POST_TABLE;
if ( isset( $tables['postmeta'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE' ) )
   $tables['postmeta'] = CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE; } return $tables;}
` but it didn't work. Do you see what may be wrong in this code?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have exactly the same content accesible in a subdirectory. I just need an extra **slug** in the url. My website will be accesible by both urls but with different templates. This way I could change the language in a clean way with the change of the template in the other site and gain from performance. I tried before that some expensive translation plugins but they were very heavy. I am building a social site and it was slowing down a lot with the use of these complex plugins. I believe that this is the cleanest way for the translation but I cannot filter the

Comment: core function with my snippet inside functions.php. I just need to add `if ( isset( $tables['posts'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_TABLE' ) )
    $tables['posts'] = CUSTOM_POST_TABLE;

   if ( isset( $tables['postmeta'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE' ) )
    $tables['postmeta'] = CUSTOM_POST_META_TABLE;` How could I do that?